# How to run flask server as portable elf

Tags: javascript, python, flask, electron

Hello i am working on a small project using electron js and flask.

I was wondering if there is a way to compile my flask server as an exe.

And run it in the background so the frontend(electron js) can send get and post requests

to my url e.g(get("http://localhost:5050")) something like that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was found and it was because i was not including the line

app.run(port=<any_port>) # dont use 80

so i fixed it hope this helps some of you

The line i used is:
app.run(debug=True,port=5050)